# Convert a JSON string returned from web API to JSON object

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hbase

I am writing a code to get JSON data from a web API and ultimately want to put it into `HBASE` table using `Phoenix`.

Initial piece of code that I am using to get data from web API is returning me data in form of a string:

```
class Health() {
 def getHealthData() {
  val userRDD = df.select("ID", "PERMISSION_T", "UPDATE_T", "HEALTHTID").rdd;
  val newData = userRDD.map(
   (
    row => {
     {
      var ID = row(0).toString // User ID
      var permT = row(1).toString // access token
      var rT = row(2).toString // refresh token
      var healthID = row(3).toString // fitbit user id
      var forDate = "2018-12-04"
      val hUrl = s "web api url"
      try {
       --Piece of code to connect to web api-- --
        hJsonStr = heartHandler.handleResponse(heartResponse).trim
       println(s "=============In TRY(Print hJsonStr) ============$hJsonStr")
      }
      heartClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
     } catch {
      case unauthorized:
       Exception => {
        println(s "Unknown exception: $hUrl")
        RecoverToken()
       }
     }
     def RecoverToken(): Unit = {
      println("<<<<<<<<<< Recover Token >>>>>>>>>")
      val recoverUrl = "recover url"
     }
     //heartJson
     //heartJsonStr
     "ID:" + ID + s "--$hUrl -- $hJsonStr -- " //+ accessToken  //+ "--" + activitiesJsonStr
    };
   }
  )
 );
 newData.collect.foreach {
  println
 }


 val fb = new Fitbit(); // initialize new fitbit object
 fb.getFitBitData(); // call function to fetch data
```

Now I want to convert this string having inbuilt JSON values to a proper JSON object so that I can put it into `HBASE`. I need to do this using Spark, Scala on Zappelin.

Below is sample data I am getting from web API using above code:

> ID:XYZ1--web url --
>   {"activities-heart":[{"dateTime":"2018-12-18","value":{"customHeartRateZones":[],"heartRateZones":[{"caloriesOut":714.31496,"max":88,"min":30,"minutes":667,"name":"Out
>   of
>   Range"},{"caloriesOut":240.01076,"max":123,"min":88,"minutes":66,"name":"Fat
>   Burn"},{"caloriesOut":0,"max":150,"min":123,"minutes":4,"name":"Cardio"},{"caloriesOut":0,"max":220,"min":150,"minutes":0,"name":"Peak"}],"restingHeartRate":62}}]}
>   --  ID:XYZ2--web url --  --

I have tried importing few `JSON` libraries and used below code but it failed due to syntax errors:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
val parsed = parse(newData).asInstanceOf[JObject]
parse(newData).asInstanceOf[JObject]
```

Comment: your response is not a pure JSON and contains some String appended to it, `ID:XYZ1--web url --`, So before parsing you need to remove these Strings. Also I would Recommend using data-frame API where you can directly read a JSON String and finally write the dataframe to HBase using hortonworks SHC, https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc

Comment: Thanks @vindev. Being new to working on json I was apparently trying it wrong way. After removing the string I was able to convert it into a JSON object inside the loop itself.

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

After suggestion from @vindev, I apparently realized I needed to remove additional string before trying to convert JSON string to JSON object. Once I did that I was able to convert it inside the loop. I used below piece of code after getting the value of `hJsonStr` in the code:

```
hJsonStr = heartHandler.handleResponse(heartResponse).trim

import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
val parsedHJsonStr = parse(hJsonStr)
```